# igraph, creating network graph

Tags: r, igraph

I am a complete beginner to igraph so please be easy on me. I am trying to create a network map with a 2x9 table I have now. However, the error messages says

> Error in graph.adjacency.dense(adjmatrix, mode = mode, weighted =
>   weighted,  :    At structure_generators.c:274 : Non-square matrix,
>   Non-square matrix

Any comments?

The code I have:

```
network <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(data, mode="undirected", diag=F)

plot(network)
```

Comment: Please show us `dput(data)`

Comment: I suspect you have an edgelist and not an adjacency matrix. You may want to try `graph_from_edgelist` instead.